# Writing a function to run a F-test with two separate shapiro-wilks tests conducted inside the function

Tags: r

> The function should perform as follows: The function takes the
> arguments: x1, x2, alt = "two-sided", lev = 0.95, where the equality
> indicates the default value.
>
> •The arguments x1 and x2 are the X1 and X2 samples, respectively.
>
> •The argument alt is the alternative hypothesis whose two other
> possible values are "greater" and "less".
>
> •The argument lev is the confidence level 1 −α. ii. The function
> returns an R list containing the test statistic, p-value, confidence
> level, and confidence interval.
>
> iii. Inside the function, two Shapiro-Wilk tests of normality are
> conducted separately for the two samples (note the normality
> assumption at the beginning of the problem). If one or both p-values
> are less than 0.05, a warning message is printed out explaining the
> situation.

Here is what I have come up with so far but not sure how to create one function to run both:

```
library(stats)
x1 <- c(103, 94, 110, 87, 98, 102, 86, 98, 109, 92)
x2 <- c(97, 82, 123, 92, 175, 88, 118, 81, 165, 97, 134, 92, 87, 114)
var.test(x1, x2, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)

shapiro.test(x1)$p.value < 0.05|shapiro.test(x2)$p.value < 0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

1. Your task is to write a *function*, so you should have something like this:

```
my_function <- function(x1, x2, alt = "two-sided", level = 0.95){
  # fill in the body of the function here
}
```

You can do whatever you need to do in the body of the function.

2. Recall that in R, the last evaluated line of a function is automatically its returned value. So, you might choose to have your last line be `list(...)` as described in the problem statement.
3. It will be useful to store results of tests, etc. as *variables* inside your function, e.g. `test_output_1 <- ...` so that you can reference those things later in the body of your function.

Comment: So is the body of the function supposed to be the steps of the f-test (finding variance, f-statistic, p-value, etc.)?

Comment: Reading your description of the problem, it looks like your function should first run Shapiro-Wilk tests of normality (and output a warning message if either vector appears to be sufficiently non-normal), then to execute `var.test()`. Note that you should use the parameters that got passed into your function, i.e. `var.test(x1, x2, alternative = alt, conf.level = level)`.